# how to make requests with ajax faster (asp.net vs mvc)

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

i find a lot of websites that have some parts in the page that uses ajax much more faster than i used to see ajax requests

like changing views using tabs 
when i click a tab it changes content very fast than i used to in my web applications using Asp.Net and Ajax Control Toolkit

and also a very quick paging in repeaters or grids than i ever developed in my web apps

like this website
http://www.filgoal.com/English/DefaultDynamic.aspx

so i need to know which technology used to achieve this
this website is developed using .net

but i need to know 
is this needs another technology to learn (from where can i learn it)

or is it just asp.net + ajax
or whth other technology

is it MVC

also i want to know if MVC is better than asp.net + ajax 
in concern with performance

thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically there are the two popular technologies:

1. Classic ASP.NET WebForms using Microsoft AJAX with UpdatePanels and the Ajax Control Toolkit
2. ASP.NET MVC with jquery

Both can make AJAX requests fast. It is impossible to say which is better. It will very much depend on your needs. There are sites which use those technologies with success. You should be aware that with both you can make fast and responsive web sites if you use them correctly.

With ASP.NET MVC and jQuery you have full control over the HTML and the contents of the AJAX requests/responses, it is a bit closer to the metal than UpdatePanels as there's a ViewState to persist.

One important aspect of making responsive web sites is sending querying and sending only the data that needs to be shown on the client. For example if you have some paginated grid on your page you should perform pagination at the database level and send only the records that are currently being displayed on the client.

Comment: 3. ASP.NET WebForms with jquery. We frequently use ajax, and we definitely don't use the ajax toolkit, nor do we use MVC.

Comment: @ScottE, yes there are many scenarios, I just decided two cover two of the most popular and widely used in my answer.

Answer (score 2):

It's not really a case of X technology versus Y technology. They all have their merits.

A well tuned JQuery + ASP.Net MVC site should work as well as any ASP.Net site. Knowing how to optimise is the most important thing.

Tips:

- Google PageSpeed, Yahoo YSlow and
  Firebug are essential tools.
- Only use AJAX where you need it, otherwise do it on page request.
  Calling the server twice, when the
  information can be gained once (for
  rather neglibigle performance) is
  generally the worse option
- Try and use JQuery 1.4+, this is optimised to faster in newer browsers
- As David Robbins has already posted the above link, I won't bother but it's an excellent insight into performance increases.

Regards,
Jamie

Answer (score 1):

Dave Ward's blog can help explain best practices for Ajax and trimming down the data sent to and from your server.  See my SO answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/777523/asp-net-ajax-vs-jquery-in-asp-net-mvc/778853#778853).  In some cases you can turn off view state and get your data via PageMethods.  Dave's blog has good insight into what you can do.

Answer (score 1):

I am now Microsoft certified trainer in various subjects including ASP.NET and I've always heard questions like yours.
I can tell you from my experience that ASP.NET MVC is very different from ASP.NET WebForms and one of those differences is the greater control that you have in MVC for HTML rendering. This can control virtually all the details of how to display the webpage, also takes much more work to detail to give a good appearance, a little different from what happens in WebForms. To be able to build a view much faster, actually AjaxControlToolkit is not the best idea and I'm starting to believe that either WebForms although there will always be people who think otherwise. With the AjaxControlToolkit, many use the UpdatePanel, which also is not a good idea, this allows you to use Ajax in a simple way without having to dirty your hands, but takes away the power you could ever have.
You ask well, to build most performant views at first you would have to learn the following:

- ASP.NET MVC (You learn almost from scratch a new way to make applications, if you never did you use PHP for example)
- jQuery (A
  javascript library, this is the secret of speed and versatility of many sites).
- jQuery Plugins (There are many among them jqgrid, jstree, spinner, and more, you control them  by hand, you have to forget the drag-and-drop)
- JSON (it's a way to pass and receive data between an application and javascript or query)
- REST (is an alternative to SOAP services)

Hope this helps, if you have more questions you can contact me at my email

Answer (score 0):

i am asking about similar websites but thesse sites are developed using asp.net but it has a very fast ajax performance so i want to know which technology to use to achieve similar performance

wheneve i use paging or tabbing with ajax updatepanel and ajax control toolkit

it takes about 10 to 30 seconds depending on data and page design and page controls

but for example this page http://www.filgoal.com/English/DefaultDynamic.aspx

is having a very fast resonse for tabing and paging regardless the data is big or small nor the page have a lot of controls or not and regardless any other thing affecting the request of the page

and also this page have a filtering drop down that is performing fast than i can implement using update panel http://www.filgoal.com/English/AllNews.aspx?CatID=1

this page is aspx page but i need to know if the website like this need

1- asp.net or mvc or this does not differ in this issue concerning the ajax performance

2- is this ajax only or ajax + other technology or no ajax at all (it is other technology)